# Изменение картинки при наведении CSS на адаптивной странице

Tags: html, css, bootstrap

Мне нужно, чтобы при наведении курсором картинка менялась, а в мобильной версии перемещалась вниз и адаптировалась под размер экрана. Вместо этого в мобильной версии изображение становится очень маленьким.

```
     <div class="row">
       <div class="col">
            <p></p>
       </div>
       <div class="col-md-4 col-xs-12 picturesklava1">
            <a class="picturesklava"></a>
        </div>
    </div
```

Так выглядит структура контейнера.

```
.picturesklava {
    text-decoration: none;
    outline: none;
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 12px 20px;
    margin: 10px 20px;
}

a.picturesklava {
    background: url("image/klava.jpg");
    display: block;
    height: 100%;
    background-size: contain;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
}

a.picturesklava:hover {
    background: url("image/komiks.jpg");
    display: block;
    height: 100%;
    background-size: contain;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
}

.picturesklava:hover {
    -webkit-transition: all 1s ease;
    -moz-transition: all 1s ease;
    -o-transition: all 1s ease;
    -ms-transition: all 1s ease;
    transition: all 1s ease;
}
```

Изображения я вставила в виде спрайтов. При наведении картинка плавно меняется. При уменьшении экрана адаптируется под размер div. Но как только размер экрана уменьшается до col-xs, а div с картинкой расширяется на весь экран, картинка становится очень маленькой.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как сделать так, чтобы картинка на мобильном экране спускалась вниз и адаптировалась под комфортный размер?

Comment: Если используйте в вопросах/ответах html, css, js тогда используйте специальный фрагмент кода. Если не знайте как это делается скажу. Нажмите вот на эту кнопку (http://prntscr.com/ol6dyw) и ставьте код там.

Comment: @Alt_F4 я бы удалила этот вопрос, потому что сама в итоге догадалась, как решить проблему. А фрагмент кода я вставить не могу, потому что это портфолио - придётся вставлять большой фрагмент с текстом + картинки из папки вставляются, а не из интернета.

Comment: Вопрос нужно удалять если он личный, относиться вашему проекту или слишком банальный. А так оставьте может кто нибудь когда то посмотрит и решит свою проблему.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В конечном итоге я сделала так. Теперь картинка адаптивная, пусть и через костыли.

HTML

```
<div class="row">
<div class="col">
<p><a class="komicsklava"><img src="image/klava.jpg"></a></p>
</div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
a.komicsklava {
background:url('image/komiks.jpg') 0 0 no-repeat;
float: right;
margin: 0px 0px 0px 15px;
background-size: 280px;
}

a.komicsklava img {
    opacity:1;
    transition:opacity .5s;
    float:right;
    width: 280px;
    text-align: center;
}
a.komicsklava:hover img {
    opacity:0;
    transition:opacity .5s;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 414px) {
    a.komicsklava img {
        width: 200px;
    } 
    a.komicsklava {
        background-size: 200px;
    } 
    }

@media screen and (max-width: 320px) {
    a.komicsklava img {
        width: 150px;
    } 
    a.komicsklava {
        background-size: 150px;
    } 
    }
```